# Java Equivalent for HTML::TableExtract

Tags: java, perl, html-parsing

Can anyone please suggest a library for Java which is similar to perl module [HTML::TableExtract](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/HTML-TableExtract/HTML/TableExtract.pm.html). The one of the noted feature of this module is it can helps the user to identify the nested tables easily by using depth and count. I used some libraries like JSoup, HTML parser and HTML Unit. But till now I don't anything close to the HTML::TableExtract module. So can anyone here please suggest me some equivalent to this module in Java if any? Because what i am trying to do is searching for the keyword in every tables and if it is present i am going to extract table. In case of nested tables, i want to extract only the table that as the keyword not the parent table also. Thanks in advance

@Łukasz Rżanek please consider the below HTML code

```
<html>
<table border=3 cellpadding=10>
<tr>
  <td valign=top>
    Content 1
  </td><td>
    Content 2<p>

    <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
    </table><p>

    Content 7
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Here I want to extract only the table which contains Content 3. How can I do that using JSoup?

Comment: What's wrong with JSoup selectors and/or DOM navigation? It's few lines of code!

Comment: I am using JSoup only. But the problem that I am facing is if the keyword present in the nested table(child table) then I cant able to extract that child table. I am very new to JSoup so I might not be using proper approach. So if you have any other approach of doing it please let me know.

Comment: Can you pleas provide HTML code or something - I don't really understand the problem since in JSoup evrything seems to be so easy right now...

Comment: @Łukasz Rżanek  Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You might need to add some additional logic.**

Check & let me know if this is what you wanted?

```
 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("**//HTML File Path//**"), "utf-8");
    Elements elements = doc.getElementsContainingOwnText("**//Text to Search//**");
    for(Element element : elements) {
        Element table = getImmediateParentTable(element);
        System.out.println(table.outerHtml());
    }
}

public static Element getImmediateParentTable(Element element) {
    while(element.tagName().equals("table")) {
        return element;
    }
    return getImmediateParentTable(element.parent());
}
```